# What should I do when my boss tells me to make passwords the same as usernames by default in our software?

Tags: security, passwords

My boss is against requiring our users to have secure passwords, even going so far to request they be setup by default to have passwords the same as their username. What should I do in this situation? What would you do?

**Update** - Some users have brought up the question of whether the application needs high security. This isn't credit card information for example but does include sensitive information and a mailing list management and sending functionality.

Comment: Will this only be used on a secure network?

Comment: No, publicly available website

Comment: This is a violation of Sarbanes-Oxley, if you (or a client company) are a public company.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the best case you can for strong passwords and then, unfortunately, if they do not see your point of view either do what they asked or find a better job.

Comment: When you work for THE MAN, you have to do what THE MAN says . . . but argue your case first

Comment: If what THE MAN says goes against your professional responsibility, you do not have to do what THE MAN says. If your boss requires you to do things unlawful, you are not even allowed to comply.

Comment: State your case in an email with proper deference and save everything (IE forward the email response to YOUR personal email account so it doesn't 'disappear').  Finally remember THE BOSS is THE BOSS, most of the time when you fight THE BOSS --- YOU LOSE!!!

Comment: @Jacco - Its not criminal, merely stupid. I would suggest to the OP that he keep emails of the decision so it doesn't come back to bite him

Comment: @Freddy - I'd be very interested to hear what government has a law against using your username as a password.

Comment: @Steve I'm not saying it is criminal, just wanted to point out that there are times that you do not have to obey your boss. (and yes, if you fight your boss, you are likely to lose)

Comment: Bruce Schneier says something like this in one of his books: if you're concerned about your data, you should use Blowfish. if you're concerned about your job, you should AES. Nobody will fire you for choosing the NSA standard for security in case it fails.

Answer (score 7):

What you're told.

...
Then respecfully let the superior know in writing what problems that will cause.

Do not CC anyone.  This is my opinion, of course.  If you CC it will look obvious.  You really just want security but you have to cover yourself.  You don't have to be a horse's behind about it though.

Keep it in your sent box, print it, whatever, if you are truly concerned.

edit - You do what you're told unless it is some sort of question of moral turpitude.  Then you simply document what you did and why you did it.  Just remember that if you do not document it - it did not happen.  Documenting is something you should always be doing.

Comment: On the email, I would send it with something that gets the superior to confirm it i.e. along the lines: please reply if we are proceeding with this.

Comment: "Yes, sir (or ma'am).  I  know you are the boss and I'll do whatever you ask.  I just wanted you to be aware of what might happen.  Please let me know so I know how to proceed.  Thank you."

You know.  Like Number One in Star Trek.  They do what they're told but they remind the Captain sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

As a compromise there are way better defaults, like using the user's serial number, year of birth, initials, some combination, depending what you have on hand.  Not the most secure but  not the least either.

Answer (score 2):

Does your application **require** high security?  If the data controlled by your software is not sensitive and the risk to the user is low, perhaps you really don't need strong passwords.

If your app does pose a significant risk to the user if passwords are allowed to be weak, you should make that case as best you can, in writing.  If you can quantify risk and liability, do so, but ultimately you will have to leave the decision up to your superiors.

Comment: well if you need password that means you need security, if you don't need it you should use e-mail/username only not username+pass. This just makes it worse, because now you got false sense of security.

Comment: Good question mwigdahl. I thought about this after posting my questions. I'll post an update to clarify.

Comment: +1 not all password-protected software requires security. sometimes its just an easy way to associate preferences, etc. UX first.

Comment: +1 only program security if it is required e.g. risk, auditors request

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with a *default* password the same as the username provided that the system requests that the user creates a new password the first time the user logs in. You then allow anything as a password if there is low security requirement. If you're handling sensitive data then password strength needs to be of an appropriate level. You haven't said what data you're hiding. There's no point in having super strong passwords (12 chars, lower case, upper case, digit and symbol and no words from dictionary) if it's an intranet based time tracking system. If you're accessing something like a tax record database then you'd need at least two level authentication - string password and one time key generation.

Comment: time tracking systems even only internal ones can be used to commit fraud by creating false records to be used to charge the customer (and being easiliy able to place the blame on someone else if it is caught). The security of passwords is just as important for internal applications.

Comment: Yes, you need to keep passwords secret, but the strength is dependant on the need to protect the data and/or keep an audit trail. You don't need to keep your time tracking system in Fort Knox. You do need keep child benefit data, for example, secure (and away from CDs!)

Answer (score 1):

You should hit him hard. Explain him/her what sort of bad publicity might happen because of this, also depends on the data, *data protection act* and similar stuff can actually cause serious liability. Basically doing it such can be considered as a software defect therefore company can be responsible for the results.

Basically you need to give him a reason which will bite him, scare him. That's how you sell security and insurance :)

If you boss can't figure out such a simple thing and can't trust guys like you at the end, maybe you should start looking for a new place which you can actually use your own potential instead of dealing with these sort of issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is poor security.

If it can result in, for example, identify theft for your users, then you have a very serious social responsibility to improve the security.  You are essentially dealing with people's lives.  Go to your boss, go to his or her boss.  Print out these comments and bring them along.  Go to your legal department and tell them how much exposure this causes.  If your company was dumping toxic waste whistle blower laws would apply.  Personal information and identify theft is no less serious.  Do everything in writing to cover yourself and to provide a paper trail of evidence for the lawsuits that will surely follow.  Don't allow your company to deny any knowledge of the risk after the fact.  Companies that knowingly implement horrible security that results in identify theft should fail in the market place and deserve nothing but shame, ridicule and failure.

If on the other hand this poor security can result in comparatively minor things then your your effort to improve the security can also be scaled back from what I describe above.

Answer (score 1):

Email him your concern (in a non-aggressive way). Give the logical attack vector, reveal what will be exposed. Close by asking for his confirmation taht this is his instruction. Then send to him (only him, as previously suggested)

Email archive both your original email and his confirmation. This will cover you if something happens.

Answer (score 0):

Argue the case for having stronger passwords but also make a compromise.  Have the passwords as defaulting to the username with certain letters replaced with numbers perhaps?  This all depends on the system as well.  If this is an internal system, it could be quite hard for somebody to gain access to the system & do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

Do what your boss says, but make the passwords expire within a relatively short time period.

Answer (score 0):

I would put together a summary document on password policies, benefits of strong passwords, etc and submit it to him for review and try and make it part of company policy.  If they still don't like it then do what they ask, as they are the end client and you have done your part to educate them of the pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

why using user/pasword in the first?

- to log user activity?
- the operating system asks for it?

if you want to connect an action (whatever) with an user, I as an user would require that my password be safe!

if your boss is afraid, that he may loose "knowledge", if a user is away, and he needs to get access to that uesers data, require everyone to write down his password in a sealed envelope.

if your boss does not trust you, kündige!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Slough may be onto something - but it might be too harsh.

Maybe take a combination approach.

Do what`s asked - but when presenting it, make sure it breaks, or you have some mechanism that will show how or why it is not a secure approach. (This will go through a review process before being implemented right?)

Also find any documentation that describes "best coding practices" from respected industry peers either in books or online or even office colleagues that may be able to back up your point of view. Present your sources, and if their ignored, you've done your duty and due diligence, and the final outcome will rest on the superiors shoulders.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider what is behind the request to have it that way first.

Is it really an active user with username+password what should be being set up in the first place? i.e. perhaps the user should be receiving an email with a link to activate :)

When does the sensitive information comes into the system? Assuming it is input by the user, just have an activation step where the user changes the password (or is the first time (s)he has a password for that matter).

Notice that if you are working with sensitive information, it is likely there is a law relating to it. I would also look into that, if it is illegal it makes for a strong case, and in that case you should Really consider saying plain no (explaining the reason first of course).

Answer (score 0):

Did he say they had to be all lowercase...
Did he explicitly say they had to not include numbers...

Answer (score 0):

You should hack into his account. Then he will know why username=password dont work.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, where they didn't want to use a secure password &/or lock down their computers.

Then it happened our website had been hacked into (not b/c of a password breach, but b/c of flawed component/module for the CMS that we used - but that's a different story) and in a few different occasions, people have logged into the exec's computer to view a few inappropriate things.

The reason for this explanation is to say that it wasn't until this and a few other case studies that I brought to their attention that they understood just how important it is for secure passwords.

As a solution, you may try to do some research on case studies where a breach has occurred on systems or sites where the information stored or protected wasn't terribly important, but the damaged cause and money it took to recover was substantial - such as someone setting up a phishing scam on your site, the holding hostage a server or site & having to wipe clean the whole box to start over, or some other type of breach.

Anyways, take it for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind that you might want to share with your boss -

1. The biggest security threat isn't outsiders, it's the folks you work with.  If there has been someone fired with cause since you've been there, bring that up with your boss - "What if XXXX had access to other people's accounts?"  That person many not steal data, but they may try to vandalize the system or mess with data out of spite.  Or could they even share that data with a competitor?
2. Propose a somewhat stronger default as a compromise - username and 4 digits of home phone number.  It's not much stronger but it does make guessing a little harder.
3. People can make fairly secure passwords by using mnemonics.  However, you need to train people in how to do that.  Offer to hold a session with your users on how to create secure passwords.  Honestly, it's not just good for where they work but for anyone who shops or banks online.  Something that's easy for IT people who have to juggle multiple passwords may be harder for others.

BTW, I found a nice javascript generator of mnemonic passwords.

http://digitarald.de/playground/mnemonic-password-generator/

Answer (score 0):

I've found situations where a password is shared by several people, because sometimes security is less important than other stuff. Specially in intranets.

A solution can be to store the IP address of each user. It's a security measure closer to security cameras than to locks, but it might be enough for what your boss has in mind.